# Slideshow of images that goes in a loop (html/js)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi all I am trying to make a slideshow of images that goes in an endless loop in my website. I have researched several websites and is still unable to get the code right as only the image set in the html code is showing and there is no change in the image ....may I ask what I am doing wrong?
Here are my codes which is involved in the slideshow:

javascript:

```
    var imageArray = ["media/Chicken Itza.jpg", "media/Christ the Redeemer.jpg", "media/Colosseum.jpg", "media/Great Wall of China.jpg", "media/Machu Picchu.jpg", "media/Petra.jpg", "media/TajMahal.jpeg"]
    var imageIndex = 0; 
    var mainImage = document.getElementById('mainImage')
    mainImage.src = imageArray[0]

    function slideshow() {
        mainImage.innerHTML(imageArray[imageIndex]);
        imageIndex = imageIndex++;
        if (imageIndex > imageArray.length - 1) {
            imageIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```

html:

```
<body onload="slideshow()">
<img id="mainImage"class="mainslides animate-fading" src="media/Chicken Itza.jpg">
</body>
```

As for my full code here it is:
html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="author(s)" content="Nathan , Jacob , Tee Kiat">
    <meta name="description" content="FED project by Nathan Jacob and Tee Kiat">
    <title>FED assignment (7 wonders of the world)</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="7 wonders.css">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="slideshow()">

    <div id="hmenu" class="hamburger_menu">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">x</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="main_gwow">The 7 wonders of the world<br>=====================</a>
        <a href="#" id="gwow1">Great Wall of China</a><br><!--China-->
        <a href="#" id="gwow2">Petra</a><br><!--Jordan-->
        <a href="#" id="gwow3">Christ the Redeemer</a><br><!--Brazil-->
        <a href="#" id="gwow4">Machu Picchu</a><br><!--Peru-->
        <a href="#" id="gwow5">Chicken Itza</a><br><!--Mexico-->
        <a href="#" id="gwow6">Colosseum</a><br><!--Italy-->
        <a href="#" id="gwow7">Taj Mahal</a><!--India-->
    </div>
        <span id="hamspan" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="openNav()">&#9776</span>
        <h1 id="title">The 7 wonders of the World</h1><br>

    <section id="generalimg">
        <img id="mainImage"class="mainslides animate-fading" src="media/Chicken Itza.jpg">
    </section>    


</body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
var imageArray = ["media/Chicken Itza.jpg", "media/Christ the Redeemer.jpg", "media/Colosseum.jpg", "media/Great Wall of China.jpg", "media/Machu Picchu.jpg", "media/Petra.jpg", "media/TajMahal.jpeg"]
var imageIndex = 0;
var mainImage = document.getElementById('mainImage')
mainImage.src = imageArray[0]

function slideshow() {
    mainImage.innerHTML(imageArray[imageIndex]);
    imageIndex = imageIndex++;
    if (imageIndex > imageArray.length - 1) {
        imageIndex = 0;
    }
    setTimeout(slideshow, 2000); //this line is added
}


function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("hmenu").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("hmenu").style.width = "0";
}
```

css:

```
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.mainslides {
   width:450px;
   height:500px; 

}
.animate-fading {
         animation: fading 5s infinite
}

@keyframes fading {
    0% {
        opacity: 0
    }   

    50% {
        opacity: 1
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}
}
figcaption{
    font-style:italic;
}

/*DO NOT TOUCH*/
h1,#hmenu,section{
    text-align:center;
}
.hamburger_menu {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.hamburger_menu a { 
    padding-top:5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#gwow1:hover, #gwow2:hover, #gwow3:hover, #gwow4:hover, #gwow5:hover, #gwow6:hover, #gwow7:hover,#main_gwow {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.hamburger_menu .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .hamburger_menu {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }

        .hamburger_menu a {
            font-size: 18px;
        }
}

#hamspan {
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have researched several websites and is still unable to get the code
>   right as only the image set in the html code is showing and there is
>   no change in the image ....may I ask what I am doing wrong?

Just that you are not at all invoking the `slideshow` method again!

Add the following line by the **end of the method** to *change the image every 2 seconds*.

```
setTimeout( slideshow, 2000 ); //this line is added
```

Also you need to set the `src` property of image instead of its `innerHTML`

```
mainImage.src = imageArray[imageIndex];
```

or

```
mainImage.setAttribute( "src", imageArray[imageIndex] );
```

**i.e.**

```
function slideshow() {
    mainImage.src = imageArray[imageIndex]; //this line is changed as well
    imageIndex = imageIndex++;
    if (imageIndex > imageArray.length - 1) {
        imageIndex = 0;
    }
    setTimeout( slideshow, 2000 ); //this line is added
}
```

Comment: Hi I have just added it but there is no difference

Comment: @nTIAO You need to set the src property instead of `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the changes that what @guruvinder372 told and still you need to make one important change for fixing the carousal. Look at the following statement.

```
imageIndex = imageIndex++;
```

When the function calls, it will always assign the value `imageIndex` as `0` only. Because the above statement will assign the value first then it will increase. You have to increase the value first then you need to assign like below.

```
imageIndex = ++imageIndex;
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/q50abf9k/)

In the above demo like you can't see the images, but you can use `F12` to check the image `src` is getting updated or not.

**JS**

```
var imageArray = ["media/Chicken Itza.jpg", "media/Christ the Redeemer.jpg", "media/Colosseum.jpg", "media/Great Wall of China.jpg", "media/Machu Picchu.jpg", "media/Petra.jpg", "media/TajMahal.jpeg"]
var imageIndex = 0; 
var mainImage = document.getElementById('mainImage');
mainImage.src = imageArray[0];

function slideshow() {
   mainImage.src = imageArray[imageIndex]; //this line is changed as well
   imageIndex = ++imageIndex;
   if (imageIndex > imageArray.length - 1) {
       imageIndex = 0;
   }
   setTimeout( slideshow, 2000 ); //this line is added
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body bgcolor="white" onload="slideshow()">
  <img id="mainImage"class="mainslides animate-fading" src="media/Chicken Itza.jpg" width="200" height="200">
</body>
```

Comment: Hi I  have used chrome to run my webpage and I just checked that I got an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null"

Comment: write your script after body fully loaded. It is clearly saying that it is trying to access the id `mainImage` before the element loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function slideshow() {
  setInterval(function (){
    mainImage.src = imageArray[imageIndex];
    imageIndex++;
    if (imageIndex > imageArray.length - 1) {
      imageIndex = 0;
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```